# java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.model.FreeStyleProject

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to execute pipeline script in Jenkins.
Here is my script:

```
import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS
@NonCPS
def getJobVariable(jobName,varName){ 
    job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName)
        newJob = job.getLastBuild()
    return newJob.getEnvVars().get(varName,null)
}




node{
    stage 'props'

    api = build job: 'Props'
    buildID =  api.getNumber()
    build job: 'Parameterized', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'string_parameter', value: getJobVariable('Props','filename')]];

}
```

But I am constantly getting NotSerializableException. I guess, something wrong in my getJobVariable method. Please, help

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've made some tests, cause I've the same issue in my pipeline jobs (for Matrix).

The solution is to put `def` before `job` or the name of Object (here `Job`) before your declaration.

After the `NotSerializableException` disappear.

If this does not solve your problem, you can also add `@NonCPS` flag before your declaration. See the official documentation: [serializing-local-variables](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#serializing-local-variables).

Comment: @Sviatlana Is the answer helped you? because of I have the same issue, but this answer doesn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

Add the following:

```
job = null
```

after

```
newJob = job.getLastBuild()
```

Answer (score 4):

Jenkins stages needs to be serialized so that they can survive job & jenkins restarts.
Now if you have some variable which have NotSerializable still exists after the stage `[Pipeline] // stage` then we get this error.

So we should set the variable to null before it touches the stage boundary

further read https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#serializing-local-variables

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers are really helpful, thank all of you. I get the same issue, and adding a `def` to the var, or set the var to null, both can fix my issue.

I just want to add some of my own understanding.
In Jenkins, define a var without "def", the var is considered as a global var.

```
@NonCPS
def rename(nodeName, needOffline, reason=''){
    hudson = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
    nodeObj = hudson.slaves.findAll { it.nodeName == nodeName }
    // some other logic
    hudson.save()
}
```

In the above example, both `hudson` and `nodeObj` are global variables, and non-serializable, so will lead to `java.io.NotSerializableException`.

#### Solution 1, add def to the two variables(So the variables are considered as local variables):

```
@NonCPS
def rename(nodeName, needOffline, reason=''){
    def hudson = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
    def nodeObj = hudson.slaves.findAll { it.nodeName == nodeName }
    // some other logic
    hudson.save()
}
```

#### Solution 2, set the two variables to null after they are used:

```
@NonCPS
def rename(nodeName, needOffline, reason=''){
    hudson = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
    nodeObj = hudson.slaves.findAll { it.nodeName == nodeName }
    // some other logic
    hudson.save()
    hudson = null
    nodeObj = null
}
```

Personally, I prefer the first approach, if I define the variable as **local** with `def` at the beginning, I no longer need to worry about the variable scope any more.